# Regular expression to check for special characters except space

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to check for special characters in a string EXCEPT spaces and delete them.

Ex: input = "Oh Boy!!#$" output = "Oh Boy"

Can someone help me with the regular expression to implement this in C#

Comment: How do you define special characters.  Is it only `!#$` what about `(){}[]/_=+:;'"`  This is important, because `\w` will only find letters numbers and underscores.  Often times a `'` is not a special character.

Comment: In my use case, I only want alphanumeric character and a space and delete the rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one way:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("Oh Boy!!#$", @"[^\w ]", ""));
```

Comment: This one is at least a good reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/, also the MSDN article is a must read (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). (If you're serious about it, you might also want to check out the book Mastering regular expressions from O'Reilly.)

Comment: Rad Software Regular Expression Designer really helped me sussing out Regex. http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/ It's free.